# set state then fetch htttp request during onchange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I am now dealing with a rather complex situation, where I want to

1. setState
2. using data from that updated state to make a first http request to update a previously defined state
3. using data from that updated state to make a second http request to update another previously defined state

Below is my attempt

```
async function req1() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(url1)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

async function req2() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(url2)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}


<Select options{[...]} onChange={e => {
  setState(data)
  req1()
  req2()
  }
}>
```

which seems to work in the first glance, however, since this compoenent is related with an reactive chart component [(Apex Charts, if it matters)](https://apexcharts.com/), before the new graph finalized, the graph would "fluctuate" first, using data out of nowhere to refresh the graph, which is not desirable in my opinion.

Anyway, is this the correct way to set state and then call request? Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: you need to use ```useEffect``` hook, f.e.: ```useEffect(() => { req1(); req2() })```, if you need to use the requests separately just define 2 data states and use different ```useEffect``` for each request

Answer (score 2):

You can have a useEffect that gets triggered on change of state alongwith implementation of [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) . The Implementation can be like this:

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
        .get('url1')
        .then((res) => {
            resolve(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
});
const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
        .get('url2')
        .then((res) => {
            resolve(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
});

useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([p1, p2]).then((responseArray) => {
        console.log(responseArray);
    });
}, [state]);
```

Comment: what if i need to pass parameters into these promises?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on some of how you're implementing the rest of the component, but I would create a component like this:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(props.initialData);

  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
    setState(e);
  }, []);

  const req1 = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url1) // Where do these URLs come from?
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }, []);

  const req2 = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url2) // Where do these URLs come from?
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function handleUpdate() {
      await req1();
      await req2();
    };
    handleUpdate();
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <Select options{[...]} onChange={handleChange} />
  )
}
```

Where are your `url1` and `url2` props coming from? Should they be passed in to the callback or are they stored in `state`?

**Explanation:**
The `useEffect` hook here tells React that whenever the value of `state` changes, then the function inside the effect should be run. Inside the `useEffect`, in order to use `async/await`, I've wrapped both `req` handlers in one async function to ensure they run one-after-the-other and then called that once; if that's not required and they can both fire at the same time (ie. they need not be run in the correct order) then you can remove this wrapper function and run both directly in the `useEffect` *without* `await`.

The other handlers I wrap in `useCallback` just for cleaner JSX, but I suppose that is somewhat down to preference.

Comment: I think with use of promises it can be handled gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use class based components, the 2nd argument of `setState` is a callback that's executed once the state has been set.

```
this.setState(....., ()=> {
    await req1()
    this.setState(..., ()=> {
        await req2()
        this.setState();
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, i am not using class based components....

Comment: It's not very difficult to convert class components to function components, unless you have many hooks. It does not impact other components.